# i have a string variable txt ="let me do my work" in python. I want to send this text data to postgreSQL databae

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

```
txt= 'let me do my work'


new_query="INSERT INTO speech (name) VALUES{}".format(str(txt))


cur.execute(new_query)
```

Comment: So what your query is?

Comment: That's a requirement not a question.

Comment: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "VALUESlet" i get this everytime

Comment: You are missing a space between VALUES and the value you inject into the query.
However, DON"T build queries like that, it's a security risk! Use bound parameters instead to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_query = "INSERT INTO speech (name) VALUES ('{}')".format(txt)
```

As a side note, you should avoid python-format your queries.

Here is the right (and safe) way to do it:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO speech (name) VALUES (%s)", (txt,))
```

Comment: Please do not encourage patterns like this. It know it directly's solves the OP's problem, but it's generally not a safe way of dynamically constructing queries.

Comment: @plamut you are absolutely right! Just wanted to address the OP's direct problem. I've updated my solution. Thanks for your feedback!